# How to properly edit a calendar event name in full?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I have this sample:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/rho79s7w/42/)

Code **HTML:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContent">
                <li class="active"><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">Appointments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#access-security" data-toggle="tab">Events</a></li>
            </ul>

          <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="details">
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <form>    
                          <label class="control-label">Event Name</label>
                          <input type="text" name="eventName"  id="eventName">
                          <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"> 
                      </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="access-security">
                content 0
                </div> 
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Code **JS:**

```
$(function() { // document ready

  var calendar=$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    selectable: true,   //permite sa selectezi mai multe zile
    selectHelper: true,  //coloreaza selctia ta


    eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            if(1>2){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            //  event.title = "CLICKED!";
            //  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
            //  event.title = "CLICKED!";
                $( "#submit" ).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var title = $("#eventName").val();
                    event.title = title;
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                }); 
            }

    },
    select: function(start, end, allDay)  
            {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');

                $( "#submit" ).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var title = $("#eventName").val();
                    if(title)
                    {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end,
                                    //allDay: allDay
                                },

                        true // make the event "stick"
                        );
                    }   
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');  
            },

     events: [
        {

            title  : 'titleEvent',
            start  : '2014-11-12',
             allDay : false // will make the time show
        },

    ]        

  });

});
```

What I want to do the next thing:

1.Open a pop-up with bootrstrap and I want to add an event in my calendar.(for this I used `select` function)

2.I want to edit the event name then when you click on an event added.

It is wrong the way I organized the code? At the moment it happens the `event click and select` while.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Added the tag `fullcalendar`, to help you find the answer faster.

Comment: i added fullcalendar tag now